# Content Provider for Storing files in disk as well as info in db

Tags: android, sqlite, filesystems, android-contentprovider

I am building an application which would store some information into the database and store some information in disk. I was just wondering on how should I be doing this?

Do Content Providers work for Databases only or can be used to retrieve stuff from disk? I plan to use a Content provider since I might want my data to appear in Global Search etc..

So, basically I would like to retrieve information from the database as well as disk everytime. If I can use a content provider for accessing things from disk, should I know be having two content providers or just one (which accesses SQLite as well as disk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the query method of your content provider you can fetch data from the disk/net and then return them building a [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

Here a basic [example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/WeatherListWidget/src/com/example/android/weatherlistwidget/WeatherDataProvider.html) from the android doc.

Comment: Do you think I should use one Content Provider for the db as well as disk storage or two seperate content providers?

Answer (score 2):

Sunny,

You may access data from disk, db or web in multiple ways. The reason to use or not use a ContentProvider is not due to its capability (as you build its interface to the data), but due to what needs access to that data and how you want it distributed. In essence, it is more a question of access (security level) or not. (i.e. how sensitive is your data and the tools that access them)

If you have multiple objects in multiple packages accessing the data, a ContentProvider may be the way to go. This is especially true if the multiple packages are separate applications. More importantly, ContentProviders allow generic requests for specific data. That is, an app may request a Contact by simply asking for a Contact, rather than knowing who or what is providing it.

Ultimately, the decision comes to what and how you want your data accessed. If you want it localized and you want the application to "know" exactly what it is asking for, how and from whom, a ContentProvider may or may not be your best bet as all of this can be accomplished using localized classes and custom specialized adapters to meet your needs. If you do need multiple components or programs to access your data, then it is something to consider, but the question is then about the requester and whether or not the source is important to the requester.

Your next question was that if you use a ContentProvider, should you use more than one. Again, it is your choice as to how to implement based on your needs. There are some good practices to follow, however, that may give you some guidance. Each class should really do one thing really well, and it should be specific. If your ContentProvider should provide data no matter what, then implementing both within the same Provider is possible, but can be a little tricksy. If your requester (normally an Activity) makes the distinction between disk vs db, then it should probably be multiple Providers. As much as I hate to say it, you must define what you need it to do, as all we can do is provide the choices, considerations and consequences. But hey!! That's the beautiful thing about programming! You get to choose what you need and make the solution fit those needs exactly possibly finding new ways to do things that you never could have been taught.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic